# Why can't I create a nullable enum in a constructor the same way I can create a normal enum?

Tags: c#, enums, null

So say this is my class:

```
class Devices
{
    public enum deviceType { } // This works
    public enum? deviceType { } // This doesn't work
}
```

So why doesn't public enum? deviceType not work? To my understanding, the ? symbol just makes it so the deviceType enum can be null; but instead, the second line gives me an error that reads:

```
The name 'deviceType' does not exist in the current context.
```

This is a very basic question but I'm just a bit confused as to why I can do one but not the other.

Comment: It's the same reason you can't create a `public class? Foo {}`, it's the instance of the object that is nullable, not the type itself.

Comment: @DavidG ah alright, I thought enum was just another variable type like string. So how would I go about creating a nullable enum?

Comment: You mean like `public enum MyEnum { Value1, Value2 }` and then `private MyEnum? someEnumValue;`?

Comment: Ah, yes that's correct. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had a misunderstanding of how enum works (I thought it worked like a variable like string instead of a type). @DavidG comments that it needs to be formatted like:

```
public enum MyEnum {Value1, Value2} 
private MyEnum? someEnumValue;
```